# New type of question

Tags: feature-request

We can see many questions in the site , but there might be some questions which you'll get to know yourself while working and you find a solution to it by yourself and move on. But if the question is quite important you may feel to ask yourself and to answer it by yourself(as in blog you can say).
And some people even want to explain some stuffs which they know very well just to spread the knowledge.
Even now also we can do that but it's just a normal question ,it would be great if these questions can be identified as different one where people can search to know about some concepts in some area.
I got this thought when i saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors).

Comment: _"... ask yourself and to answer it by yourself ..."_ Why do you think this needs a new feature. You can already do this easily.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for here; do you want some sort of "featured" notation for questions that have extended and/or excellent answers, or are you asking to be able to answer your own question, which is already available?

Answer (score 8):

There is no need for a new type. We have always allowed self answering, even at the same time as asking.

If you go to the "Ask Question" page, there is a checkbox at the bottom - "Answer your own question", which when ticked, opens up an answer form.

> [image: Answer your own question checkbox]

I don't see a benefit is marking such posts as "different", as a self answer is meaningless in terms of quality (that one self answers doesn't mean they know what they are talking about).

Comment: As i had mentioned in the question i know that you can answer your own question ! I requested to make a self answering questions as different type of questions. But if you think its useless and creates mess , fine you don't have to consider this.

Comment: @vins - I am asking - what's the benefit? Can you explain? Can you also explain **why** such posts should get a different treatment (the same person asking and answering is not enough)?

Comment: I thought it just encourages people to spread knowledge if you make self answering as different type of questions who don't write blogs will use your site to explain what they had learnt. But I'm sorry for wasting your time if this idea/discussion is useless.

Comment: @vins - I will ask again - how is that _better_ than what we have? We already have a mechanism for self-answering. It is not clear to me how (simply making self answered questions more distinguishable) makes things _better_. Can you clarify?

Comment: It won't make better. My intention was that to encourage people to answer even if someone has not asked that question.  Yes we can do that now , i thought making this type of question different will bring some awareness to share their knowledge.  But doing this won't make it better .